# What is difference between participle phrases and ellipsis of subject + be in adverb phrases?

Tags: grammar

When invited, she gladly said yes.

In the above sentence, my book says the sentence is formed because ‘she was’ is omitted. And the sentence is the example of ellipsis of the same subject + be in the adverb phrase.

Then what is difference with participle phrase? The above sentence cannot be seen as an example of a participle phrase?

Help me

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is it possible to see the sentence as a participle phrase which does not omit ‘when’?

Comment: The non-finite "when invited" is best analysed as a verbless clause. A finite clause can be reconstructed by adding a subject and a form of the verb "be" to give "when she was invited". Other examples include "While in Paris, I visited La rue Montmatre"; "Ed can be a real pain when drunk".